# Java Runtime.getRuntime().exec() appears to be overwriting $PATH

Tags: java, path, environment-variables, exec

For a project to automate some mutation adequacy testing, I'm trying to make GoLang from source from inside a Java program. I have been able to make it from source in the Terminal, and have tried using that command in Java's `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` command:

```
String[] envp = new String[3];
envp[0] = "CC=/usr/bin/clang";
envp[1] = "GOROOT_BOOTSTRAP=/usr/local/go";
envp[2] = "CGO_ENABLED=0";
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("./all.bash", envp, "$HOME/Desktop/go/src");
```

The equivalent command to this works fine in the Terminal. Running this code in java (And printing the output) gets the following:

```
./all.bash
##### Building Go bootstrap tool.
cmd/dist
go tool dist: FAILED: uname -r: exec: "uname": executable file not found in $PATH
```

So that's weird that it can't find `uname`. Again, if I enter `'uname'` on the Terminal, it works fine. So I found the directory of `uname` ('which uname' gives `'/usr/bin/uname'`) and set `$PATH` to that for this command:

```
String[] envp = new String[4];
envp[0] = "CC=/usr/bin/clang";
envp[1] = "GOROOT_BOOTSTRAP=/usr/local/go";
envp[2] = "CGO_ENABLED=0";
envp[3] = "PATH=/usr/bin";
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("./all.bash", envp, "$HOME/Desktop/go/src");
```

And that instead gets the output:

```
./all.bash
env: bash: No such file or directory
```

So when I set the path, it can't find the program in the directory. This suggests to me that when `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` is called, it overwrites `$PATH` to be the directory I passed it, then overwrites the environment variables I gave it. But in order for `./all.bash` to work, I need both paths to be in the `$PATH` variable. How can I do this?

On Mac OS X 10.11.6.

Comment: `envp` isn't variables to add to the environment, it's variables to set the environment to. No other variables other than the ones you specify will be made available ot the process. **You** overwrite PATH.

Comment: Oh ok. So if I want it to also be able to execute ./all.bash in the directory I give it, do I have to add that directory to $PATH too? Like "PATH=/usr/bin:$HOME/Desktop/go/src"? Or something like that, cause that gets the same error.

Comment: Probably easiest to just get your path and pass it through `System.getenv().get("PATH")`

Comment: That worked! Thank you. But two of the tests fail, and they don't when I run in Terminal. Specifically, 'os/signal' says that Current is not implemented, and 'runtime' timed out. I suppose I'll have to open a new question to get answers to that though.

Answer (score 3):

Runtime.exec was replaced by [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) twelve years ago, as part of Java 1.5.

Among its many superior features is the ability to add to the existing environment:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("./all.bash");
builder.inheritIO();

builder.directory(
    new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Desktop/go/src"));

builder.environment().put("CC", "/usr/bin/clang");
builder.environment().put("GOROOT_BOOTSTRAP", "/usr/local/go");
builder.environment().put("CGO_ENABLED", "0");

builder.start();
```