# Building Go from source fails tests when run using Java's Runtime.getRuntime().exec()

Tags: java, go, environment-variables, exec

This question is related to a previous question, here: [Java Runtime.getRuntime().exec() appears to be overwriting $PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40873863/java-runtime-getruntime-exec-appears-to-be-overwriting-path)

I am trying to build Go from source from inside a Java program. I can build it properly using Terminal, but Java's Runtime.getRuntime().exec() gets interesting results. I tried using ProcessBuilder, but could not get it to properly make Go. Using my current setup with exec(), it makes properly, but then fails two tests. Code snippet:

```
String[] envp = new String[4];
envp[0] = "CC=/usr/bin/clang";
envp[1] = "GOROOT_BOOTSTRAP=/usr/local/go";
envp[2] = "CGO_ENABLED=0";
envp[3] = "PATH=" + System.getenv().get("PATH");
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("./all.bash", envp, "$HOME/Desktop/go/src");
```

It runs properly and compiles properly, but when it gets to running the test suite, I get two errors:

```
--- FAIL: TestCurrent (0.00s)
user_test.go:24: Current: user: Current not implemented on darwin/amd64 (got &user.User{Uid:"502", Gid:"20", Username:"", Name:"", HomeDir:""})
FAIL
FAIL    os/user 0.009s
```

and a much longer one that I won't paste here due to absurd length, but it comes down to:

```
panic: test timed out after 3m0s
...
FAIL    runtime 180.056s
```

I haven't any idea why the former is failing, but for the runtime when I build from the Terminal, it says:

```
ok      runtime 19.096s
```

So something is causing that to take absurd amounts of time. I did some googling, and heard that it might be fixed if I use ARM=5 as an environment variable, but that didn't change anything. Does anyone have any idea why these tests are failing when I build from Java as opposed to the Terminal?

Comment: You could always try just running `make.bash` if the tests are not super important to you.

Comment: For the `User.Current()` to work, you need to enable cgo, which you disabled with `CGO_ENABLED=0`. See issue [here](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/6376#issuecomment-66085388).

Comment: @ivan.sim it does not, strictly speaking, "not work". It just goes to a [fallback](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/964639cc338db650ccadeafb7424bc8ebb2c0f6c/src/os/user/lookup_stubs.go#L22) implementation that trusts some env vars.

Comment: @captncraig Only true if he's using [go 1.7+](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/795e712b72802ad49b7c077964046f79c4f6586e)

Comment: Good catch. He has the new error message though so I'm guessing he's on master.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the source code for the `os/user` package, it looks like the [native user handling](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/964639cc338db650ccadeafb7424bc8ebb2c0f6c/src/os/user/lookup_unix.go#L6) depends on having cgo enabled. If cgo=0 (your case), it will fall back to the `USER` and `HOME` environment variables.

[source code in question](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/964639cc338db650ccadeafb7424bc8ebb2c0f6c/src/os/user/lookup_stubs.go#L22)

Try putting `USER=whatever` in your exec environment.

I'm afraid I'd need more information to diagnose the runtime issue.

Comment: I tried adding the environment variable "envp[4] = "USER=whatever";" but got the same error, so I tried "envp[4] = "USER=<myactualusername>";" and "envp[4] = "HOME=/Users/<myactualusername>";" (separately), but got the same error every time. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: If you want the full Runtime error, it's at http://pastebin.com/5XnGzysq

Comment: @user1914745 looks like you also need to set HOME to some value as well. Sorry.