# Issue with running a command in java

Tags: java, macos, shell, latex

Im trying to use the terminal from java to convert a tex file to pdf:

```
...
        Process pr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("pdflatex docu.tex") ;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
        String line = "";
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
...
```

and I get this error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "pdflatex": error=2, No such file or directory
```

I have the docu.tex file in the same package as the above.
When I input the command into the terminal directly it works fine and the pdf is made.

Thanks

Comment: See if providing the explicit path to `pdflatex` makes the difference.

Comment: oooooh !
Yes thanks that did the trick

Comment: Any idea why using pdfLaTeX didn't work?

Comment: Read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40873863/java-runtime-getruntime-exec-appears-to-be-overwriting-path

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify what Runtime#exec is going to use to execute your command, you can use bash like so, this should make your command execute on mac & linux (unix based) systems with bash available.

```
  final String[] executionStrings = new String[]{"/bin/bash", "-c", "pdflatex docu.tex"};
  Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executionStrings);
```

Comment: I think the main issue was not using the full path for pdflatex which made it not work for some reason

Comment: But your method worked for me too, if I changed the pdflatex to the explicit path, that is

Comment: well is the file in the classpath?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out all I had to do was find the explicit path to pdflatex(by typing "which pdflatex" in the terminal) like @PM 77-1 said, and replacing it with "pdflatex